# Coding Problems-help with AS3 quiz game

Tags: actionscript

Ok, so could someone tell me what's wrong with this script?

stop();

Start_Game.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, Start_function);

function Start_function(e:Event){
 gotoAndPlay("Question Board");
}

Comment: it's much easier to tell whats wrong with your question

Answer (score 0):

stop();

Start_Game.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, Start_function);

function Start_function(e:MouseEvent){ gotoAndPlay("Question Board"); }

Instead of e:Event, write e:MouseEvent.